# How to overlay span on card in bottom right corner?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to do thumbnail with duration in bottom right corner for video, but I don't know how to properly move span object in card (Bootstrap4). When I try to margin-left more than 50% then span object is crashing:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
   .duration {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 5px;
 }
    
    .card-img-overlay {
     position: absolute;
     margin-top: 75% !important;
        margin-left: 51% !important;
        margin-right: 0% !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card img-fluid mt-2" style="width:200px">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/img_avatar1.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">Example text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
      <span class="duration">2:42:42</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT: I solved this problem by replacing CSS like that:**

```
.duration {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top:65%;
    left:68%;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by Crashing?

Comment: I solved my problem. Check first edited post.

Answer (score 1):

You can set override padding property in the class card-img-overlay. Try following:

```
.card-img-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 85% !important;
        margin-left: 68% !important;
        margin-right: 0% !important;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Hope to help, my friend.

Comment: Thanks, I also solved my problem. Check first edited post.

Comment: @Prime_Bull: That's great, my friend :))

Answer (score 1):

OR you can just float it right like so

float:right;